# Saving with Jackon in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, jackson

I'm making a note-taking program using libgdx (a game engine). I want to save the user's notes and sheets when they hit save . First question is, is writing to JSON with Jackson the right way to do this? If it isn't, could someone tell me the right way to save? I have too much stuff for preferences and the JSon class built into libgdx isn't working for me. `toJSon` throws a `StackOverflowError`.

If Jackson is the right thing to use, how can I fix this error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
 (was java.nio.BufferUnderflowException) (through reference chain):etc`

Comment: It looks like your `POJO` classes have circular references, this is a reason why you see this exceptions. Could you add more information to your question? `POJO`'s properties, example source code how you want to serialize these classes, etc. If you want to store many different objects, you should choose something else, maybe MongoDB, LiteSQL, etc ...

Comment: Libgdx `Json` class would be the right way. If it throws a `StackoverFlowError` you need to debug to see where and why.